# Excel VBA -- Need help constructing a line of code using for loop, if statement, and message box

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

i need help in constructing a code that would basically display a message box that would act as an error message or notification message of sorts. Here's a sample code that I was thinking of that I know will work but not exactly the output I was looking for

```
lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUP).Row

for a = 1 to lr
   if Sheet1.Cells(a,1) = Date then 
      ` A whole new set of codes here that's not really an issue so i'll save time and just skip writing it down

   else MsgBox "No Data for Today!"
   end if
next a
```

I know this will work and display a msgbox with the words "No Data for Today!", but the thing is, everytime the for-loop goes for another pass, it will again display the msgbox. What I want to happen is it should only display the msgbox ONCE and only AFTER it has checked all the cells and verified that the data on those cells are NOT equal to the current date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT:

Just a brief explanation of what i'm trying to achieve. So basically, the code I provided checks every row of column A to if the data inside of it is equal to the current date right? So what I want to happen is, I wan't it to check all the cells in that range and display a MsgBox IF NONE of the cells in that range is equal to the current date, and IF THEY ARE EQUAL to the current date, then it should not display the MsgBox. I tried running the code below from @JGreenwell and it did display the right MsgBox IF all the data on the range of cells ARE NOT EQUAL to the current date, HOWEVER, if I add data in the range that is EQUAL to the current date, it still displays the msgbox even if there's at least one data that's equal to the current date.

I hope this is clearer than my original question. And I really do appreciate all the tips/advice/and help that you guys are telling me. :)

```
Dim dataFlag As Boolean
dataFlag = False 'create and set boolean type flag

for a = 1 to lr
    if Sheet1.Cells(a,1) = Date then
        ' A whole new set of codes here that's not really an issue so i'll save time and just skip writing it down

    else 
        dataFlag = True
    end if
next a

If dataFlag Then
    MsgBox "No Data for Today!"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUP).Row

for a = 1 to lr
   if Sheet1.Cells(a,1) = Date then
      ` A whole new set of codes here that's not really an issue so i'll save time and just skip writing it down

   else 
       UnFound = 1
   end if
next a
If UnFound = 1 Then MsgBox "No Data for Today!"
```

Comment: I changed the answer to conform to your change.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a *flag* instead and just display the message if the flag is set.

```vb
Dim dataFlag As Boolean
dataFlag = False 'create and set boolean type flag

for a = 1 to lr
    if Sheet1.Cells(a,1) = Date then
        ' A whole new set of codes here that's not really an issue so i'll save time and just skip writing it down

    else 
        dataFlag = True
    end if
next a

If dataFlag Then
    MsgBox "No Data for Today!"
End If
```

---

Flags are a standard programming practice that allows a *condition* to be *associated* with an *algorithm* (set of instructions). For your case, a simple **Boolean** type  works but this can also be combined with other *data structures* and/or multiple *conditions*: like setting a flag to one of several values and taking different actions based on what value the flag contains.

Comment: Thanks @JGreenwell, but I made an error on my original question, and have just edited it right now. Would this work either way?

Comment: did you intentionally remove the for loop or did you just foget to put it in your code?

Comment: Hey @JGreenwell, thanks for this and it worked beautifully, but the thing is I think I forgot to mention one little detail of what I'm trying to achieve. This does work when it doesn't find a cell that doesn't have the current date, BUT, when I added new data with the current date on the following row of the same column, it executes my code like it should but it also displays the msgbox, and I don't want that to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: One, yes I removed the Loop intentionally (it is not needed for the answer). Two, your question makes no sense with the code you posted (update your question with an explanation and example case)

Comment: @synthaxe your question makes no sense. You need to either: remove the update, upvote and accept an answer to this question, and make another question with the new issue (your can link to this one in the new one) or really work on the explanation of your problem.

Comment: I'll change my question and try to explain it better.